# Google Sheets Filter Function - How can I make data static?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Im trying to make the data that I sort using a filter function stay static in the cells that is is sorted in. I have had this problem a few times and have tried looking it up on Youtube but it seems to be more of an advanced question.

For example when I filter a row of data from one sheet to the next. It is not static data, meaning when I delete the data on the new sheet it stays there until I delete the data on the master sheet.

Please few my example spreadsheet here.
[Google Sheets Example Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RbSMhv4NTpC55lGTlWZ5ArnWygbAih1WcfUsgL42VPY/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any formula (like `FILTER`) can only process source data. It is linked to the source data permanently. Think of it as a mirror of the source data (and think of changes the formula makes to the source data as a funhouse mirror). You cannot have formula results that you change manually.

If you want a *copy* of the original data that you can change (and that will no longer be linked to the original data at all), then just select the range containing the original data, Copy it and Paste it to the new location.

If you need some kind of link or updating when the source data changes, or you want the ability to change the source data when you update the copy you made, this requires writing custom scripts. It cannot be done with formulas.